# Адаптив для google adsense

Tags: css, google-adsense

На сайте выводится реклама adsense, но на маленьких экранах от 320px часть рекламы скрыта.
Подскажите, как сделать адаптив для маленьких экранов?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код примерно такой:

```css
.single-article .code-block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px){
.single-article .code-block ins, .single-article .code-block ins iframe {
    width: 100%!important;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="code-block" style="margin: 8px 0;"><!--noindex-->
    <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: inline-block; width: 291px; height: 280px;"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-1" data-ad-slot="1" data-adsbygoogle-status="done">
        <ins id="aswift_0_expand"
             style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:291px;background-color:transparent;">
            <ins id="aswift_0_anchor"
                 style="display:block;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:291px;background-color:transparent;">
                <iframe width="291" height="280" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0"
                        allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"
                        style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:291px;height:280px;"></iframe>
            </ins>
        </ins>
    </ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script><!--/noindex-->
</div>
```

Comment: Ничего особенного не делал. Диву, в котором находится рекламный блок, указал width: 100%; в стилях, а вот рекламные блоки в Google Adsense выбирал с настройкой - адаптивные.

Comment: @Quazimorda, т.е. сейчас этим рекл. блокам нельзя добавить адаптив, нужно было выбирать изначально в настройках адаптивные рекл. блоки? Как это правильно объяснить?

Comment: По-поему, вы и сейчас можете зайти в настройки рекламных блоков гугла, сменить простые на адаптивные со всеми теми же рекламными категориями. и просто заменить код, который они предоставляют на вашем сайте.

Comment: Вот так у меня [выглядит](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6bUa/HJsVeTWYD).